# Filtering Django model with special characters from API view

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following API view:

```
class OpenWeeksAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Weeks.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OpenWeeksSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['activity', 'discipline']
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
```

I want the API filter to be able to recognize some Spanish characters within the object (á,é,í,ó,ú) and filter them using standard characters (a,e,i,o,u).

So for example, if I have an object where the field `activity` is "canción", and the user filters "cancion" instead of "canción" it retrieves the object anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) for this.
This can convert your query string to the closest ASCII representation.